# Get collection's class name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

For a model's has_many relation, I want to get the class name of that collection. If I just call `.class` it returns CollectionProxy instead of the collection's model class...

I found this way:

```
irb(main):013:0> organization.users.class.to_s
=> "Users::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy"

irb(main):014:0> organization.users.class.to_s.split('::').first
=> "Users"
```

But it seems messy/hacky, is there any other way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to look at

https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Reflection/ClassMethods.html#method-i-reflect_on_association

Something like

`Organization.reflect_on_association(:users).klass` or class_name or the like.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Rails [klass](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Reflection/AssociationReflection/klass) method and get the associated models class name like below:

```
organization.users.klass.name
```